# SwiftUI: Get toggle state from items inside a List

Tags: list, swiftui

I'm building an app where I generate a dynamic list inside a view, the items inside this list have a toggle button. If a button in the parent view is pressed and all the items have their toggle activated. Then a function is carried on.

How can I get the @state of all the list items in order to do the function when the button is pressed.

Here is some basic code for it:

```
struct OrderView: View {

  var pOrder: OrderObject

  var body: some View {

    VStack(alignment: .leading){

      Button(action: buttonAction) { Text("myBttn") }

      List(pOrder.contents, id: \.name) { item in

        Child(pOrder: item)

      }
    }
  }
}
```

And here is the code for the child view

```
struct Child: View {

  var pContents: Contents

  @State var selected: Bool = false

  var body: some View {

    Toggle(isOn: $selected){ Text("Item") }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
struct ObjectOrder: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var order = ""
    var isToggled = false

    init(order: String) {
        self.order = order
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @State var pOrder = [
        ObjectOrder(order: "Order1"),
        ObjectOrder(order: "Order2"),
        ObjectOrder(order: "Order3"),
        ObjectOrder(order: "Order4"),
        ObjectOrder(order: "Order5")
    ]

    var body: some View {

        List(pOrder.indices) { index in
            HStack {
                Text("\(self.pOrder[index].order)")
                Toggle("", isOn: self.$pOrder[index].isToggled)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Try using .indices would give you an index to your object in the array.  Adding a property to track the toggle (isToggled in the example above) would allow you to store and keep track of the objects toggled status.

Comment: This worked partially until the list changed (it's dynamic) and the ForEach failed. Just added an identifiable and worked.

Changed line:
List(pOrder.indices) { index in

List(pOder.indices, id: \.self) { index in

Comment: After spending a day for resolving such situation, finally found some worthy solution. Thanks